# Complex ASP.NET Dataform jQuery AJAX

Tags: jquery, asp.net-ajax

I have a pretty big data entry form which has many text fields , ComboBox , etc.
When I want to Do an action with jQuery AJAX for example posting Fields to a WebService for inserting a new record I have to put all input fields in a object and passing it to WebService.
For example I have Member Class Like This :

```
public class Member
{
    private string name = String.Empty;
    private string lastName = String.Empty;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }

    public string LastName
    {
        get { return lastName; }
        set { lastName = value; }
    }
}
```

I Should Define JS object Client Side and filling Properties like this :

```
var m = new Member();
m.Name = $("#txtFirstName").val();
m.LastName = $("#txtFirstName").val();
```

after that I should pass object to a Webservice and doing my serverSide Action.
So it is simple when I have under ten fields . but when I have for example twenty fields it takes long time to capture all fields from client and passing that to server.
Now my questions :

1. What are other ways to handle data entry form and passing Input fields to server?
2. Is there any framework or tool exist to make this action easier for us ?
   I will welcome your suggestions, comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using the jQuery [serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) method?

> The .serialize() method creates a text string in standard URL-encoded notation. It operates on a jQuery object representing a set of form elements. The form elements can be of several types:

```
$('form').submit(function() {
    alert($(this).serialize());
    return false;
});
```

---

You could also use the example in this SO answer: [Convert form data to JavaScript object with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184624/serialize-form-to-json-with-jquery)